# Serde custom field attribute

Tags: rust, serde

I would need a custom field attribute in serde:

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Foo {
  #[serde(customattribute)]
  pub bar: String,
}
```

I am using a reader/writer for a specific format which need a parameter to control how fields are (de)serialized. But I still want my data structure to also be (de)serialized to json, which means that I do not want to use a custom serializer.

Is it possible in serde to have custom field attributes?

Looking at serde source code it seems that attributes are hardcoded in `attrs.rs` so I am pessimistic, but maybe I missed something.

Comment: config should be in deserializer not in the structure. You are doing it wrong.

Comment: Please educate me.

Comment: Some examples for the deserializer: [a](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75936264/401059) [b](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71333006/401059)

Comment: Thanks @Caesar, but I already got a deserializer. However, in XML, a field can be an element or a attribute and I need to specify this field by field. That's why I need to provide that info on the field through an attribute.

Comment: A custom serializer can (de)serialize to JSON just fine. The whole point of Serde is to get everything into a basic data format that can be serialized to anything under the sun, including JSON. Your type doesn't actually have to be a `String` to serialize to a JSON string (notably, any field-less enums serialize to strings under `serde_json` with the default implementation). I think you want a custom serializer. Or, depending on how much you need, [`serde_with`](https://docs.rs/serde_with/latest/serde_with/) may be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Something important to understand about Serde, and other Rust libraries that use traits and derive macros, is that the attributes are information *for the derive macro* (`derive(Serialize)`). The derive macro then takes that information and generates an `impl Serialize for Foo`, and that is the *only* place the attributes get used. The serializer does not get to see the attributes.

Therefore,

1. *Anything* you can do with `#[serde]` attributes, and many things you can't, can be done by writing an `impl Serialize for Foo` yourself.
2. The `Serializer` you use doesn't get to see the attributes. It only gets to talk to the `Serialize for Foo` trait implementation. Thus, an attribute cannot *directly* communicate information to the serializer; it can only influence how the `Serialize` behaves.

Therefore, custom attributes are not the first step. The first step is to write an `impl Serialize for Foo` and an `impl Serializer for MyCustomFormat` that can cooperate to produce the results you want. Then, once you've figured that out (if it's possible), you can think about writing a derive macro that understands a custom attribute and generates your `impl Serialize for Foo` for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try writing your own attribute macro which would customize the result of `serde` and use it to add such functionality.

The general idea is to get two different structs a public one with extra fields and a private one without them. In tailor-made implementation you first deserialize the basic part of the struct and then do all other stuff to create the public one.

Incidentally, the private one can be declared within the very body of the tailor-made implementation, so that it won't be visible from the outside.

There are some examples:

https://medium.com/@unegare/rust-serde-adding-synthetic-fields-to-a-struct-54db4bafbde

https://github.com/unegare/rust-notes/blob/master/serde-custom-derive-deserialize-synthetic-fields/src/main.rs